# Gnuradio running into audio underrun when using audio source and sink at the same time

Tags: gnuradio, fsk

I wanted to calculate the BER curve for an FSK audio modem transmitting via the speakers and receiving through the mic of the computer.

I am using [Aaron Scher's FSK loopback flowgraph](http://aaronscher.com/GNU_Radio_Companion_Collection/Audio_Modem_loop_back_test_FSK.html)

The thing is, whenever I run this (i.e audio source and sink working simultaneously), I only get aUaUaU as output.
If I save the audio sink output as a wav file and then play it from my mobile phone, the message is displayed on the screen and this flowgraph works just fine.

How do I fix this?

[image: This is my flowgraph]

Comment: does it work if you just move the receiver to a separate flow graph and let both flow graphs run at once?

Comment: also, check `top`/`htop` / whatever your operating system has as process manager for how much spare CPU you've got when only running the receiver.

Comment: Are your input and output device clocks synchronized?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac that would be irrelevant here, since the audio source is not connected to the audio sink, as far as I can tell

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have moved the receiver to a separate flowgraph and it still does not work.
top shows the cpu usage for python3 (gnuradio) as 15% for a few seconds then it becomes ~150%

Comment: hm how much is that of your overal CPUs?